# How can I make a child container display block inside of a display flex container

Tags: html, css, jsx

I am trying to have 2 containers, one displaying flex(to be side by side) and a child container to display block. I can't seem to figure out how to make this work. This is what i am going for https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRlRw.png and this is what my container looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLINA.png
What can be done to have the index "58" inline with "Moderate" and the paragraph to look like the picture?

this is the JSX

```
<div className="second-col-container">
          <h2>Air Quality Index</h2>
          <div className="mod-container">
             <span className="index">58</span>

             <span className="mod">Moderate</span>
          </div>

          <div className="para-mod">
            Air quality is acceptable; however, for some pollutants there may be
            a moderate health concern for a very small number of people who are
            unusually sensitive to air pollution.
          </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.second-col-container {
  background-color: white;

  width: 250px;
  grid-area: air-index;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.second-col-container h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.para-mod {
  font-size: small;
  width: 50%;
  color: grey;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.index {
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
  color: black;
  font-size: xx-large;
  border: 3px solid rgb(223, 217, 217);
  border-left-color: rgb(255, 170, 11);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 170, 11);
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.mod-container {
  display: flex;
}

.mod {
  font-size: large;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your html a bit. You can have a second flex container with flex-direction: column.

```
<div className="second-col-container">
<h2>Air Quality Index</h2>
<div className="mod-container">
    <span className="index">58</span>
</div>

<div className="para-mod">
    <span className="mod">Moderate</span>
    <div>
    Air quality is acceptable; however, for some pollutants there may be a
    moderate health concern for a very small number of people who are
    unusually sensitive to air pollution.
    </div>
</div>
</div>;
```

CSS

```
.para-mod {
    font-size: small;
    width: 50%;
    color: grey;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```